Find next available cell in column and copy data from another column in same row into a different worksheet
The aim is to find the next available cell in column "B" in Workbooks("Job List") and copy the order number in column "A" from the row found with the empty cell in column "B" into the "Master" worksheet.
Sub nextEmptyRow()

    Dim nextEmptyCell As Range
    Dim Copy_nextEmptyCell As Range

    Set nextEmptyCell = Worksheets("Job List").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

    With Sheets("Job List")
        Set Copy_nextEmptyCell = Range(Cell.nextEmptyCell.Row, "A").Select
        Copy_nextEmptyCell.Copy
        Sheets("Master").Select
        Range("K1:L1").Select
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

End Sub


First and foremost:  Avoid .select and .activate where possible.

Going to try and break this down, because there are quite a few errors:
Sub nextEmptyRow()
    Dim nextEmptyCell As Range
    Dim Copy_nextEmptyCell As Range
    With Sheets("Job List") 'Moved this up
        Set nextEmptyCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'You did not quality Rows.Count, which would take the activesheet count; no need to select when dimensioning
        Set Copy_nextEmptyCell = nextEmptyCell.Offset(,-1) 'this line needed fixed altogether; technically you could avoid this line by using the above offset and modifying the column
        Sheets("Master").Range("K1:L1").Value = Copy_nextEmptyCell.Value 'changed to value=value, removed selects
    End With 
End Sub

Not much different, but:
Sub nextEmptyRow()
    With Sheets("Job List") 'Moved this up
        Dim copyCell as Range:  Set copyCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1,-1)
        Sheets("Master").Range("K1:L1").Value = copyCell.Value
    End With 
End Sub


This works perfectly, thank you very much indeed. I knew I was making it too complicated!

If I wanted to then fill these cells with data from another Sheet, how would I amend this? ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("K2").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Job List").Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("K3").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Job List").Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("K1:K6").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Close

@AbbyWilkins if this has resolved your post, please mark the 'check' on the left side of the answer so the post is flagged as answered.  Regarding your follow-up question in the comments, script in comments is a bit difficult to read, and without context (essentially another post), the only advice to give is to qualify all of your ranges with the sheet you want to use.... you have dot notation in your script, but I don't see a with statement, so that's the first red flag coming to mind.
